# how to create JSON API using cakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakePHP, I created the database and baked everything, I need to make JSON API (RESTFULL) to all the methods,  I made search before I post a question here but I couldn't make it work..
can any one please guide me to the detailed configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Another plugin would be https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud.

But even with cake itself you could easily acomplish a simple api, using the link to the cookbook kicaj provided.